# Not understanding the behavior of ..density

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the dataframe below, I would expect the y axis values for density be 0.6 and 0.4, yet they are 1.0. I feel there is obviously something extremely basic that I am missing about the way I am using ..density.. but am brain freezing. How would I obtain the desired behavior using ..density.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("yes","no","yes","yes","no"))
m <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a))
m + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))
```

[image]

Thanks,
--JT

Comment: add inside aes `group=1`. At the moment, `yes` and `no` belong to different groups.

Comment: Thanks again Arun. I would like to mark this as solved but I think you need to put your response as an answer?

Comment: you can write the answer yourself Jimmy and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Arun's comment:

At the moment, `yes` and `no` belong to different groups. To make them part of the same group set a grouping aesthetic:

```
m <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a , group = 1))   # 'group = 1' sets the group of all x to 1
m + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))
```